# What steps are performed when a serious event reaches an Intrusion Detection System?

Tags: network, ids

For example, you are using Snort and you just got a serious event, which states that a certain service is attacked.

What do you do with the threat source IP?

What are the steps that network event analyst performs?

Edit: Narrowing the question down, how it is dealt with such threats, instantly block ip? Gather evidence? Reroute the traffic for further analysis? I just need some behavior examples on example situations.

Edit2: Specifically, DoS/DDoS attacks.

Comment: This question is _extremely_ broad. It's very difficult to even begin to cover it. I'm gonna have to vote to put it on hold until you make it a bit narrower.

Comment: Sorry, Ren. Still very broad. Reacting to a threat depends on the nature of the threat itself. What you're asking is how to [react to _all_ threats](http://cdn.meme.li/instances/300x300/39547307.jpg).

Comment: And if it helps, there are already a number of questions on how to identify and respond to DoS or DDoS attacks.

Answer (score 4):

Look up your security procedures and invoke your incident handling process as appropriate.